# Виджет не скрывается принудительно если его родитель импортирован как модуль в основное окно

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, gui, hide

Вот такое решение у меня существует на данный момент:

**answer.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from answer_page import PageGeneral

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(35,43,50);")
        self.resize(800, 450)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)

        self.top_bar = QFrame()
        self.top_bar.setObjectName('top_bar')
        self.top_bar.setMaximumHeight(40)
        self.top_bar.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)

# StackedWidget
        self.stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(self)
        self.stackedWidget.setEnabled(True)
        self.stackedWidget.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.stackedWidget.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.stackedWidget.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Plain)
        self.stackedWidget.setObjectName("stackedWidget")
# Pages
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(PageGeneral())


# title_bar
        self.title_bar = QFrame()
        self.title_bar.setStyleSheet("background-color: transparent")
        self.title_bar.setMinimumWidth(120)
        self.gridLayout2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.title_bar)
        self.gridLayout2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout2.setSpacing(0)
        self.label_title = QLabel(
            '1 - cвернуть / развернуть, 2 - закрыть', alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_title.setObjectName('label_title')
        self.label_title.setStyleSheet("background-color: #519259")
        font = self.label_title.font()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.label_title.setFont(font)
        self.label_title.installEventFilter(self)
        self.gridLayout2.addWidget(self.label_title, 0, 0)

# max_button
        self.max_button = QPushButton('1')
        self.max_button.setMinimumHeight(40)
        self.max_button.setMaximumWidth(40)
        self.max_button.clicked.connect(self.expand_window)

# close_button
        self.close_button = QPushButton('2')
        self.close_button.setMinimumHeight(40)
        self.close_button.setMaximumWidth(40)
        self.close_button.clicked.connect(self.close_window)

        self.layout_navigation = QGridLayout(self.top_bar)
        self.layout_navigation.addWidget(self.title_bar, 0, 0)
        self.layout_navigation.addWidget(self.max_button, 0, 2)
        self.layout_navigation.addWidget(self.close_button, 0, 3)
        self.layout_navigation.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.right_bar = QFrame()
        self.right_bar.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)

        self.vbox_2 = QVBoxLayout(self.right_bar)
        self.vbox_2.addWidget(self.top_bar)
        self.vbox_2.addWidget(self.stackedWidget)
        self.vbox_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.vbox_2.setSpacing(0)

        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.hbox.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.hbox.setSpacing(0)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.right_bar)

    def expand_window(self):
        if self.isMaximized():
            self.showNormal()
            PageGeneral().wiev_widget(maxwindow=False)
        else:
            self.showMaximized()
            PageGeneral().wiev_widget(maxwindow=True)

    def close_window(self):
        self.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**answer_page.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class PageGeneral(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.page_general = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.page_general.setObjectName("page general")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.page_general)

        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.widget.resize(150, 150)
        self.widget.setStyleSheet("background-color: #006400")
        self.statusBar()

    def wiev_widget(self, maxwindow=False):
        if maxwindow == False:
            self.widget.show()
            print('Виджет widget отображается')
        elif maxwindow == True:
            self.widget.hide()
            print('Виджет widget прячется')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = PageGeneral()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Главным исполняемым из которых является **`answer.py`**. 
Нужно чтобы при расширении окна на весь экран виджет прятался, а при нормализации снова появлялся.

Но проблема в том что отображается он в любом случае, хотя судя по принтам скрипты в условии проходят до конца.

Однако если добавить в **`answer_page.py`** кнопку и привязать к ней добавленную функцию из основного файла `expand_window()`, то при исполнение кода в этом файле, всё работает как надо, но только локально.

При импорте функциональность опять же пропадает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте экземпляр класса `PageGeneral()`:

```
    ...
    self.pageGeneral = PageGeneral()                                # +++
    self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.pageGeneral)                  # +++
    ...
```

и работайте с экземпляром:

```
...
def expand_window(self):
#        print(f'expand_window(self): {self.isMaximized()}')
    if self.isMaximized():
        self.showNormal()
#            PageGeneral().wiev_widget(maxwindow=False)
        self.pageGeneral.wiev_widget(maxwindow=False)               # +++
    else:
        self.showMaximized()
#            PageGeneral().wiev_widget(maxwindow=True)
        self.pageGeneral.wiev_widget(maxwindow=True)                # +++
...
```

---

**answer.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

from answer_page import PageGeneral


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(35,43,50);")
        self.resize(800, 450)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)

        self.top_bar = QFrame()
        self.top_bar.setObjectName('top_bar')
        self.top_bar.setMaximumHeight(40)
        self.top_bar.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)

# StackedWidget
        self.stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(self)
        self.stackedWidget.setEnabled(True)
        self.stackedWidget.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.stackedWidget.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.stackedWidget.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Plain)
        self.stackedWidget.setObjectName("stackedWidget")

# Pages
        self.pageGeneral = PageGeneral()                                # +++
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.pageGeneral)                  # +++

# title_bar
        self.title_bar = QFrame()
        self.title_bar.setStyleSheet("background-color: transparent")
        self.title_bar.setMinimumWidth(120)
        self.gridLayout2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.title_bar)
        self.gridLayout2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout2.setSpacing(0)
        self.label_title = QLabel(
            '1 - cвернуть / развернуть, 2 - закрыть', alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_title.setObjectName('label_title')
        self.label_title.setStyleSheet("background-color: #519259")
        font = self.label_title.font()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.label_title.setFont(font)
        self.label_title.installEventFilter(self)
        self.gridLayout2.addWidget(self.label_title, 0, 0)

# max_button
        self.max_button = QPushButton('1')
        self.max_button.setMinimumHeight(40)
        self.max_button.setMaximumWidth(40)
        self.max_button.clicked.connect(self.expand_window)

# close_button
        self.close_button = QPushButton('2')
        self.close_button.setMinimumHeight(40)
        self.close_button.setMaximumWidth(40)
        self.close_button.clicked.connect(self.close_window)

        self.layout_navigation = QGridLayout(self.top_bar)
        self.layout_navigation.addWidget(self.title_bar, 0, 0)
        self.layout_navigation.addWidget(self.max_button, 0, 2)
        self.layout_navigation.addWidget(self.close_button, 0, 3)
        self.layout_navigation.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.right_bar = QFrame()
        self.right_bar.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)

        self.vbox_2 = QVBoxLayout(self.right_bar)
        self.vbox_2.addWidget(self.top_bar)
        self.vbox_2.addWidget(self.stackedWidget)
        self.vbox_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.vbox_2.setSpacing(0)

        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.hbox.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.hbox.setSpacing(0)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.right_bar)

    def expand_window(self):
#        print(f'expand_window(self): {self.isMaximized()}')
        if self.isMaximized():
            self.showNormal()
#            PageGeneral().wiev_widget(maxwindow=False)
            self.pageGeneral.wiev_widget(maxwindow=False)               # +++
        else:
            self.showMaximized()
#            PageGeneral().wiev_widget(maxwindow=True)
            self.pageGeneral.wiev_widget(maxwindow=True)                # +++

    def close_window(self):
        self.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]